# Servlet mapping - what is the difference between PATH-MAPPING and EXTENSION-MAPPING

Tags: servlets

Servlet mapping - what is the difference between `PATH-MAPPING` and `EXTENSION-MAPPING`.

I know about `PATH-MAPPING`, but unable to understand the need for `EXTENSION-MAPPING`.
Please provide an example as I have invested almost 2 hours but didn't get any answer (proper answer)

Answer (score 1):

It's not nearly so commonly used, but extension mapping allows a servlet to handle all files with a particular extension. For example, it allows you to define a servlet that will handle all paths that match `*.pdf`, *as long as there isn't a path-mapped servlet that matches as well*. That last part is important; exact-matching and path-matching happen first, so extension mapping only overrides the default servlet's behaviour.

Here's how you'd set one up.

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>HandlePDFs</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.pdf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You don't want to use extension mapping if you're developing webapps; prefix mapping is much better for that (and you can organize the handling of URLs within a webapp in any way you want).

Comment: +1 From the spec: `If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g. .jsp), the servlet container will try to match a servlet that handles requests for the extension. An extension is defined as the part of the last segment after the last ’.’ character`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, but the _real_ key is that it's only checked for _after_ path mappings. That restricts its use very strongly.